# Disable angular-translate key interpolation

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Is it possible to prevent angular/angular-translate from interpolating the translation key ? example:

```
<div translate="This is a test translation in language: {{lang}}"></div>
```

Trying to do something like this will fail because Angular will try to interpolate the `{{lang}}` instead of just giving it as  a string to angular-translate.

I'm aware of the fact that angular-translate excepts short keys but I'm trying to prevent having to translate it to my native language (so just return the key as translation for that language)

Comment: translate="{{'This is a test translation in language: {{lang}}'}}" << have you tried this?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov yes, that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Does escaping interpolation markers help?

```html
<div translate="This is a test translation in language: \\{\\{lang\\}\\}"></div>
```